# Yii2 admin module accessing via URL domain.com/admin/login

Tags: php, routes, yii2

I've created admin module, and my website root points to `web` directory.

So what changes I've to do to achieve `domain.com/admin` as the base URL for my module. Any action inside admin module should look like `domain.com/admin/controller/action`

Here is my directory structure.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your urlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

In root of your file put .htaccess

```
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin(.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
```

put second .htaccess in /backend folder.

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on


# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . web
#RewriteRule . index.php
```

and put another .htaccess in backend/web/ folder like

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box yii2 handles routes like *module/controller/action* when you request them like this: example.com/index.php?r=module/controller/action. To make them look like you want you need:

Configure your `urlManager`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

Enable your module in config:

```
'modules' => [
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Module',
    ],
],
```

And configure rewrite rule in *.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```